# Dataframe seems to produce correct result but not going into conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hi I'm relatively new to python and I'm trying to make a change in a framework that reads csv files and my function is supposed to check 3 things: first whether the row is pertinent or rather whether the names align, second check whether the variable type is a int32 or a float32, and third check if the particular cell we are looking at contains the string 'NO_DATA'. If all these 3 things are true then we wish to modify the cell with the 'NO_DATA' value with a -1 or -1.1 depending on whether the data type is an int32 or float32 respectively. The way I'm checking the first 2 conditions is with the data_rows variable which is an array of dictionaries that contain relevant info (i.e. data type and column name). And when it's just these two conditions the code works fine and will make changes to data as expected. however with the third condition it always seems to fail, which is odd to me as when I print out the data of the cell (base_df[item][idx]) it looks like it is correctly printing 'NO_DATA' but the code will not go into the conditional when I add this third condition. for clarity this is the condition code I believe is failing: base_df[item][idx] == 'NO_DATA'. In the pictures the first shows what the column looks like, notice we see there is a 'NO_DATA' value at the top and in the second photo when we print base_df[item][idx] for that exact same column, with the same column name, we get that the first output is 'NO_DATA' which is why I'm confused as to why it's the code's not reaching the conditional. [image: column with 'NO_DATA' in it] [image: output from base_df[item][idx]]

```
#self.__base_dfs is dictionary where the key is csv file names and value is info in csv file read in by pandas
        for csv_file_keyword, base_df in self.__base_dfs.items():


            for item in base_df:

                for index in range(len(data_rows)):

                    if item == data_rows[index]['column_name']:

                        print("*** FIRST base_df ***")
                        print(base_df[item])
                        break

            if self.__valid_csv_files[csv_file_keyword]:

                
                for item in base_df:
                    
                    for idx in range(len(base_df[item])):
                        
                        print("*** base_df[item][idx] ***")
                        print(item)
                        print(base_df[item][idx])
                        
                        for index in range(len(data_rows)):


                            #ISSUE IS IN THIS CONDITIONAL FIX THIS: and base_df[item][idx] == 'NO_DATA'!!!!!!!
                            if item == data_rows[index]['column_name'] and data_rows[index]['column_type'] == 'int32' and base_df[item][idx] == 'NO_DATA':
                                
                                print('CHANGE')

                                base_df[item][idx] = -1

                            if item == data_rows[index]['column_name'] and data_rows[index]['column_type'] == 'float32' and base_df[item][idx] == 'NO_DATA':
                    
                                #print('CHANGE')

                                base_df[item][idx] = -1.1

            for item in base_df:

                for index in range(len(data_rows)):

                    if item == data_rows[index]['column_name']:

                        print("*** LAST base_df ***")
                        print(base_df[item])
                        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to arise from the way pandas handles strings in DataFrames. When comparing strings, you need to ensure that there's an exact match, including the case sensitivity and any trailing spaces. It is possible that the value `'NO_DATA'` in the DataFrame has hidden characters, such as spaces or is in a different case (like `'No_Data'` or `'no_data'`).

You can update your conditions as following:

```
import numpy as np
# ...
if base_df[item].dtype == np.int32 and base_df[item].str.strip().str.upper()[idx] == 'NO_DATA':
    base_df.at[idx, item] = -1
elif base_df[item].dtype == np.float32 and base_df[item].str.strip().str.upper()[idx] == 'NO_DATA':
    base_df.at[idx, item] = -1.1
```

Here's what I did:

1. **String Matching:** Using `str.strip()` to remove any leading/trailing spaces and `str.upper()` to match the case.
2. **Pandas String Methods:** Using the `.str` accessor to perform vectorized string operations. When dealing with pandas series, direct string methods may not work as expected.
3. **Checking Data Types:** Using `base_df[item].dtype` to get the data type of the column and compare it to NumPy types.

This should most probably work in your case.

Comment: Hi OM Bharatiya I appreciate your help, the new knowledge you provide will be useful in my use of pandas in the future and what you say makes sense regarding the potential issue, however I used the code you provided and it still doesn't seem like it has solved the issue. I tried printing print("*** base_df[item].str.strip().str.upper()[idx] ***")
print(base_df[item].str.strip().str.upper()[idx]) and it returns the error: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which means base_df[item].dtype is not of type string, but rather a object type, in this case how to I compare it?

Comment: In pandas, a column with mixed types is often represented as object type, which can include a mixture of strings, numbers, or other types. To address this issue, you need to ensure that the data you are comparing is treated as a string. You can use the `astype(str)` before applying string methods like `strip()` and `upper()`. Add it as follows:

`stripped_upper_values = base_df[item].astype(str).str.strip().str.upper()`

and conditions: `if base_df[item].dtype == np.int32 and stripped_upper_values[idx] == 'NO_DATA':`

Do it for both cases. Hope it fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help my friend! Hope you have a wonderful time during the holidays!